# How to use standard deviation calculated in pivot table as error bars on chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table

I would like to draw a graph of the measurement values over time. Here is my pivot table:
[image]

There are 6 types of measurements (represented in columns) and 20 points in time (rows). Each measurement was repeated 5 times. Pivot table shows average of those 5 measurements and standard deviation of them.

I want to plot how results of those measurements change over time, so average values should be represented as line chart and standard deviation should be shown as error bars.

Here is what I see when I create a chart from my pivot table:

[image]

The problem here is that standard deviation is being drawn as line chart and not as error bars. I can't find any way to hide those values from chart without removing them from pivot table and generate error bars from them.

Below picture represent what I actually want to acomplish. It's how pivot chart looks like when I remove standard deviation from pivot table and enable error bars. Error bars are incorrent - they all have the same values, so I presume Excel just made up some example value.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sample about the source data?

Answer (score 1):

A pivot chart plots all data in the pivot table (except subtotals and grand totals). So if your pivot table has averages and standard deviations, both sets of lines will appear in the chart.

There are two ways to approach this.

1. Make a regular chart of the average data in the pivot table (see [Making Regular Charts from Pivot Tables](https://peltiertech.com/regular-charts-from-pivot-tables/)). Then add custom error bars using the calculated standard deviations in the pivot table (see [Custom Error Bars in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/custom-error-bars-in-excel-charts/)).
2. Make two pivot tables, one with averages, one with standard deviations. Make a pivot chart from the first pivot table, then add custom error bars using calculations in the other pivot table.